# Undefined when searching with Find Mongoose Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I receive an array of products that I need to search for with Mongoose, so I use Find passing the _id of each product. But when going through the array and trying to search, I only receive the data of the first product, for the others I always receive undefined.

This is my code:

```
const calc = async (details) => { 
    
    let grandSubtotal = 0; }
    console.log(details);
    for (let i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
        let verifyProduct = await Product.find({ _id: details[i]._id});
        console.log(verifyProduct[i].salePrice);  //It only shows the first product, the others are undefined

.......

    }
```

In my MongoDB database I have the products all saved with salePrice always, in this way:

```
{
  "_id": "628fa841cde1d960c675ee24",
  "barCode": "0000075053765",
  "idProduct": "03",
  "name": "MALBORO ARTESANAL 20",
  "desc": "PAQUETE 20 CIGARROS",
  "presentation": "PIECES",
  "salePrice": 550,
  "purchasePrice": 526,
  "stock": 0,
  "available": true,
  "img": [],
  "status": false
}
```

How can I obtain the salePrice information of all the products that I receive since for now I only receive information on the first one and the others are always undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this because, you are using `.find({})`

> let verifyProduct = await Product.find({ _id: details[i]._id});

You're querying using `.find({ _id: details[i]._id})`, you will always have result in the form of `[{..onevalue at 0..}]` because `.find()` returns result in an `[]`

so, when you execute the loop for the first time, your `i` will be `0` and so when you access the `verifyProduct[0].salePrice` it will have value. But when your `i` become `1`, your `verifyProduct` will still have result at `0` position only.

**Fix:**

```
const calc = async (details) => {
  let grandSubtotal = 0;
  console.log(details);
  for (let i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
    let verifyProduct = await Product.findById(details[i]._id);
    // no array, so access it directly
    console.log(verifyProduct.salePrice);
  }
}
```

since you are querying by `_id`, you can use [`.findById({})`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-findById) instead of `.find()`.

Answer (score 0):

Database query in a for loop is super inefficient. You should use the [`$in`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) MongoDB  operator to select multiple documents at once.

#### Example

```
const arrayOfIds = ["631318a217f73aa43a58855d", "63132ba7525da531e171c964"];

Product.find({ _id: { $in: arrayOfIds }});
```

Comment: The problem with $in, in my case, is that I don't just get an array of ids but I get an array with objects inside with different values

Comment: Use the [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create array of ids seems to be cleaner solution for me. `const arrayOfIds = originalArray.map(product => product._id)`

Comment: Yes, I did that but I noticed that it gives me an array again, I mean that $in again I have an array. So I don't know how convenient it is to be looping through arrays or using filter of two arrays. I don't know, but I think it's more complex.